# Define member function using concatenating

Tags: prolog

How to define member (X,L) using concatenating relationship? could anyone explain the method?

```
concatenate([],L,L).
concatenate([X|L],L2,[X|CL]):-concatenate(L,L2,CL).
```

It is given concatenating goals

Answer (score 1):

Try the behaviour of concatenate/3 in your Prolog interpreter (the command line, AKA REPL) for this *specific* query:

```
?- L=[1,2,3], concatenate(_,[X|_],L).
```

This pattern it's actually what you need... but the details of adding a predicate member/2 will depend on the actual Prolog implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it `member/2` **predicate**, not a **member function**, 
it sounds like the `C++` term.

Here's `concat_member/2`:

`concat_member( X, Xs ) :- concat( _ , [ X | _ ], Xs ).`